# How to stop auto adding of namespace in vs2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, settings

Whenever I add new *.cs file following namespace adds up, I am working on console app;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I am just using `using System;` I just want System namespace every time I add .cs file. System namespace should come up by default not others. I have to delete every time I add `.cs` file rest of namespace. I like neat coding so I want following sitting on my **Visual Studio 2013**.

Comment: Why not just add a shortcut for "sort and organize usings" and apply that whenever you want? That's what I do - so it doesn't matter if I've got extra `using` directives etc. The directives when the file is first created are just one special case of the more general case of cleanup

Comment: You can easily remove unused using: `Right Click > Organize Usings > Remove Unused Usings`